# Can you create/store/maintain relational data on CouchDB?

Tags: mysql, nosql, relational-database, couchdb

I am looking for offline database because the app needs to support read operations in the areas without internet. However, once the machine is brought into an area with the internet access, we should be able to connect to the internet and should be able see the updated data.

Comment: I'd use SQLite to store relational data while offline, not CouchDB.

Comment: @Bill Karwin, somewhere I read that the DB size is restricted to 2 GB for SQLite.  Also, SQLite doesn't handle multi user login. Is there any solution to handle these issues?

Comment: MySQL, PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, Informix, ...? There are many multi-user RDBMS products, both free and commercial, available to be installed locally, without access to the internet. Why go to the trouble of converting relational data into non-relational and back again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pouchdb. Couchdb and pouchdb is best pair for offline data sync.

Comment: yeah, our team decided to use couch DB since offline data sync is our main concern.